# Is it possible to enable vendor-disabled user accounts in rooted device with Android 6.0?

Tags: multi-user

I recently purchased a Doogee X5 max pro device, which comes with a version of Android 6.0. I understand that this version of Android supports multiple user accounts, but it seems that the vendor disabled this possibility, at least it is not accessible in the standard way.

Since it is a relatively new device there are not many custom ROM's available.

Is there a way that I can enable user accounts? My phone is rooted and it has TWRP installed. If I have to do it from a computer, then preferably Linux, though I do have access to a Windows machine as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot access the multi user menu in the settings app it is possible that the manufacturer completely removed that feature from its android version. Luckily you can install a similar feature [manually](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116327/how-do-i-manage-users-on-my-htc-one-with-android-5/116331#116331) but you need the Xposed Framework.